# Custom Ribbon Action always enabled? Logic to disable not working

Tags: 2013, provider-hosted-app

I recently created a new Sharepoint App to add a custom ribbon action to my ribbon bar.

I want to make sure the button is only enabled when at least one selection to a document selection is made. Disabled otherwise.

I followed a couple of other answers about adding this logic, but nothing is seeming to work... it is always enabled.

This is my code..

```
<CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                          EnabledScript="javascript: function enableCopyLinksButton() {
                                        console.log('running script');
                                        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                                        console.log(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context).length);
                                        var result = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context).length >= 1;
                                        return result;
                                      }
                                      enableCopyLinksButton();"
                          CommandAction="~remoteAppUrl/CustomActionTarget.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}&amp;SPSource={Source}&amp;SPListURLDir={ListUrlDir}&amp;SPAppWebUrl={AppWebUrl}&amp;SPHostWebUrl={HostWebUrl}"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
```

I added some console logging there to even see if anything is fired in the console, but i see nothing. So not even convinced that the script is even firing at all..

Am i approaching this wrong by any chance?
(I also tried to add `javascript:alert('test');` to my `CommandAction`, but then the app breaks when I try deploy it. Seems like it doesnt like it anyways)

Answer (score 0):

In your `EnabledScript`, you both define the function and call it. Actually, the code right after `javascript:` must be the code returning `true` or `false`. And you cannot defined a function in there.

You have to embed your a JavaScript function `enableCopyLinksButton` elsewhere and only call it:

```
EnabledScript="javascript: enableCopyLinksButton();"
```

You then have to define the function `enableCopyLinksButton` in the master page, or in a script custom action (see attribute `ScriptSrc` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ms460194.aspx), or in `SPWeb.CustomJavaScriptFileUrl` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.customjavascriptfileurl.aspx), or by any other mean.

Comment: Thanks Evariste. I came across this other answer - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132096/enable-disable-button-on-ribbon-when-content-type-selected - and there the person says you can use 'inline scripting' when defining and calling the function. This not true anymore? I'm also hoping to keep all code related to the app within the app. Hoping to avoid having the need to add additional code outside of the app package... But if need be, I will have to.. :)

Comment: You probably can keep everything in the app by declaring the script file as a module, and referencing it from `ScriptSrc` tag in your custom action.